Authentication Issue with Salesforce gRPC Pub/Sub API for GetSchema and GetTopic Methods
I'm trying to interact with the Salesforce gRPC Pub/Sub API, specifically the GetSchema and GetTopic methods, on a sandbox instance. However, I'm encountering the following error:

An authentication exception occurred. Provide valid authentication via metadata headers.

error code -  sfdc.platform.eventbus.grpc.service.auth.error
Interestingly, the Subscribe method works fine, but the GetSchema and GetTopic methods do not.
I've ensured that the accesstoken,tenantid, instanceurl are included in the metadata headers, but these two methods still fail while Subscribe succeeds. Has anyone faced a similar issue or knows what might be causing this discrepancy?
P.S: I am using the OAuth 2.0 JWT token
metadata.NewOutgoingContext(ctx, metadata.Pairs(
        "accesstoken", response.AccessToken,
        "tenantid", response.OrgId,
        "instanceurl", response.InstanceURL,
    ))

Salesforce PubSub API rejecting access token tried this one as well but no luck
